Young's inequality for convolutions in $l^2$
Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $|a_n|$ is in $l^2$. Let
$$
c_m = \sum_{k=0}^m a_k a_{m-k}.
$$
I wonder if the following inequality holds
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty |c_m|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty |a_m|^2\right)^2.
$$
This seems to be the discrete version of Young's inequality for convolutions, but I am not finding a proof or a good reference.

The inequality is false (see Lxm's comment below). Is the following true
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{|c_m|^2}{m+1} \leq \left( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|a_m|^2 \right)^2.$$

The inequality is false; just look at $(1,a,0,0,\dots)$ where $a>0$. I thought the usual Young's inequality for convolution says $|f*g|_1\leq|f|_1\cdot|g|_1$?

@Lxm Thank you. Please see the revised question.

I think the best you can do is weighted Young's inequality $\left( \sum_m \frac{1}{m+1} \left( \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{k+1} f(k) g(m-k) \right)^2 \right)^{1/2} \le \left( \sum_{m} \frac{1}{m+1} |f(m)|^2\right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{m} \frac{1}{m+1} |g(m)|\right)  $
